# Find the general solution to this Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $z=f(x,y)$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, I have to solve the following differential equation:
$$ \frac{z \,dz+y \,dy}{y^2+z^2}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2}+(x-a)}.$$
I have not seen anything like this before so any ideas/hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let rewrite equation:
$$\frac{z\,dz+y\,dy}{y^2+z^2}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2}+(x-a)}.$$
$$\frac{d(y^2+z^2)}{y^2+z^2}=\frac{2dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2}+(x-a)}.$$
With changing $y^2+z^2=t^2$ and $x-a=s$:
$$\frac{2tdt}{t^2}=\frac{2ds}{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}+s}.$$
or
$$\frac{\sqrt{s^2+t^2}+s}{t}dt=ds$$
This is a homogeneous equation. Another substitution $s=ut$ gives us
$$\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$
and we conclude
$\ln(t)=\sinh^{-1}(u)+C$. Now we return main variables.

Comment: Is the $C$ in the $\sinh^{-1}$ function?

Comment: It's Integration constant

Comment: Yeah I got that, but do you mean $\sinh^{-1}(u+C)$ or $\sinh^{-1}(u)+C$?

Comment: Got that! Thanks.